# RavenDB Results Transformers on list inside documents (RavenDB 2.5)

Tags: ravendb

Considering this scenario:

1. Example Document:

   ```
   {
       "Order": {
           "Products": [
               {
                   "ProductCode": 131131,
                   "Description": "shipped product",
                   "Shipped": true
               },
               {
                   "ProductCode": 33333,
                   "Description": "not shipped product",
                   "Shipped": false
               },
               {
                   "ProductCode": 87138,
                   "Description": "shipped product",
                   "Shipped": true
               },
           ]
       }
   }
   ```
2. Index + Transformer

   ```
   public class MyIndex : AbstractMultiMapIndexCreationTask<ProductViewModel>
   {
       public MyIndex()
       {
           this.AddMapForAll<MyDocuments>(docs => from doc in docs
                                                  from product in doc.Order.Products
                                                  select new ProductViewModel
                                                   {
                                                       Shipped = product.Shipped
                                                   });
       }
   }

   public class MyTransformer : AbstractTransformerCreationTask<MyDocuments>
   {
       public MyTransformer()
       {
           this.TransformResults = docs => from doc in docs
                                           from product in doc.Order.Products
                                           select new ProductViewModel
                                               {
                                                   ProductCode = product.ProductCode,
                                                   Description = product.Description,
                                                   Shipped = product.Shipped
                                               };
       }
   }
   ```
3. Query:
   i want to query these documents by field 'shipped' and use a transform to extract all values of products list:

   ```
     var products = this.session.Query<ProductViewModel, MyIndex>()
           .Where(x => x.Shipped == true) // or .Where(x => x.Shipped == false)
           .TransformWith<MyTransformer, ProductViewModel>()
           .ToList();
   ```

The problem: the query result is the SAME changing the where clause (Shipped:true/Shipped:false), and it's obvious that i want first and third document when Shipped:true and the second when Shipped:false;
I'm using RavenDB 2.5.2874;

Comment: First, why are you using a MultiMap index, you are only mapping from one entity? And are the ProductViewModel the actual stored entity? What is the MyDocuments class? I think you want to make a regular index on the "MyDocuments" entity and then transform on that into your view models.

Comment: @Jaynard this is a simple example of my scenario.. MyDocuments is a generic class extended several times; ProductViewModel isn't the stored entity; i only need to extract from all documents the list of all products and filter that; mapping in the map all fields that i need and doing .ProjectFromIndexFieldsInto<ProductViewModel> in the query it works, but why using the transform it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question why you get the same results with both Shipped:true/false:

```
from doc in docs
from product in doc.Order.Products
select new ProductViewModel
{
    Shipped = product.Shipped
});
```

this will create one index entry for all Order/Products on the entity you're indexing. This is called a Cartesian (or fanout) index. To clarify:

A document with id 'MyDocuments/1' with an order containing three products with Shipped set to true, false and true will create the following index entries:

```
Id             Shipped
MyDocuments/1  true
MyDocuments/1  false
MyDocuments/1  true
```

When you're querying this index Raven will look for the indexed properties and then fetch the related document id. In this case both Shipped: true/false points to the same document. That's why you get the same result.

I wouldn't recommend using fanout indexes as it might cause performance issues when 1 document could generate an unknown amount of index entries.

There are several possible solutions to this, but the first one you should ask yourself is if you might want to model your data a bit differently? Can a product really be shipped? Isn't it the order (containing products) that's either shipped or not?

Hope this helps!